# How do I remove a comma from a variable in php so I can save it as a float value?

Tags: php, mysql

I take data from steam and this is what I get outputed

```
{"success":true,"lowest_price":"$0.82","volume":"17,485","median_price":"$0.82"}
```

So I want to take the data to mysql database and with lowest_price and medain_price I can just do it like that

```
$filename_median_price          =       "https://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?appid=730&currency=1&market_hash_name=Operation%20Breakout%20Weapon%20Case";
    $data_median_price          =       file_get_contents($filename_median_price);
    $array_median_price         =       json_decode($data_median_price, true);

    $median_price1              =       $array_median_price["median_price"];
    $median_price               =       strtr("$median_price1","$"," ");
```

and then update it to the data base.

But with volume I can't because there is a comma instead of a dot and in the database it only updates me to 17 instead of 17485. So how can I remove the comma so I can update data properly.

Comment: `$something = str_replace(',', '', $volume);`

Comment: But SO is really not a replacement for looking through the [PHP manual.](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply replace the comma for a period and cast it to a type you desire, you can read more on this [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php)

```
(float)str_replace(',', '.', '123,456')
```